# LINQ Fluent API version of left join query

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have a LINQ query that is working just fine but I would like to know how to convert it to be in the LINQ fluent API format. I have tried searching Google for a decent tutorial on fluent API to try and learn this my self but there does not seem to be one.

This is the query I want to convert:

```
from s in db.Sections
join f in db.Files
    on s.LogoFileID equals f.ID into s_f
where s.RouteName == SectionRoute
from x in s_f.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new GameSectionVM
{
    SectionID = s.ID,
    GameTitle = s.Title,
    LogoFileName = x.FileName,
    Synopsis = s.Synopsi
}).Single();
```

Comment: Take each operation one at a time.  Look up the documentation and examples of joining queries, and look at the documentation of the appropriate methods.  Join the data in one method call.  When you've done that, filter out the rows that meet your filter criteria.  Continue to do this for each operation that you have.

Comment: I know how to do the select and the where but I have been unable to find anything I can understand in the joins. Like I said in the OP I have searched for tutorials but have not found anything.

Comment: First off, rather than looking for tutorials on translating query syntax to method syntax, just look for how to join two queries.  There are *lots* of tutorials showing you how to do that.  And even if there weren't, just only need to look at the documentation for the LINQ methods in MSDN to see what operations there are, what they do, and how to call them, including lots of examples.  Additionally, if there are parts that you *do* know how to do, then don't ask how to do those.  Ask about what you don't know how to do, rather than asking us to do everything when you've already done 75% of it.

Comment: Resharper can do this for you, Outer Joins are equivelant to GroupJoin in LINQ method syntax

Comment: @Servy I was looking for general tutorials on fluent API not on converting things. Most things I found where not about fluent API but using the code method I displayed.

Comment: @Alan Thank you, everytime I looked for ways to do this using `.Join` they never seemed relevant, I did not know it was called a GroupJoin. Also thanks for the note about ReSharper, never heard of it before but looks like something I will be installing.

Comment: You will like Linqpad. It shows linq query syntax as fluent syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper gives the following conversion:

```
(db.Sections.GroupJoin(db.Files, s => s.LogoFileID, f => f.ID, (s, s_f) => new { s, s_f })
          .Where(@t => s.RouteName == SectionRoute)
          .SelectMany(@t => s_f.DefaultIfEmpty(), (@t, x) => new GameSectionVM
                                                             {
                                                                 SectionID = s.ID,
                                                                 GameTitle = s.Title,
                                                                 LogoFileName = x.FileName,
                                                                 Synopsis = s.Synopsi
                                                             })).Single();
```

I cannot vouch for its accuracy, but it should at least help you get started. the GroupJoin appears to be what you need to do the outer join at least.

Comment: Thanks I will play around with the GroupJoin, I was trying to use a normal Join but nothing I found helped. I guess that was because I was looking for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what would work in your circumstance because you haven't provided the details of all the involved types; but, something along the lines of this:

```
(db.Sections.GroupJoin(db.Files, s => s.LogoFileID, f => f.ID, (s, s_f) => new {s, s_f})
    .Where(t => t.s.RouteName == SectionRoute)
    .SelectMany(t => t.s_f.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, x) => new GameSectionVM
    {
        SectionID = t.s.ID,
        GameTitle = t.s.Title,
        LogoFileName = x.FileName,
        Synopsis = t.s.Synopsis
    })).Single();
```

Assumes the `Section` class exists and has a correctly named property `Synopsis` (not `Sysnopsi`)

Comment: Yes, `Sysnopsi` was as type-o. Had to retype the code since it is on my laptop which I could not get online at the time. Not sure what more information you want. The code I posted works already so the ties between tables is all there.