# How to convert this SQL statement with left join, grouping to EF Core Linq?

Tags: c#, join, ef-core-2.1

I have 2 tables, Events and EventTracking.

**Event**

```
id 
Name
Order
```

**EventTracking**

```
Id
EventId
Details
CreatedDate
```

I am trying to recreate basically this query below in EF Core.

```
SELECT 
    events.NAME, 
    COUNT(eventtrackings.details) AS Count 
FROM   
    events 
LEFT JOIN 
    eventtrackings ON events.id = eventtrackings.eventid 
WHERE
    eventtrackings.CreatedDate > '4/22/2019'
GROUP BY 
    NAME, eventtrackings.CreatedDate
ORDER BY
    events.Order
```

I want everything in Events to be shown, but the filtering is on the tracking part.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. Wouldn't something simple as this work? `_context.Events.Select(evt => new { Name = evt.Name, Count = evt.EventTrackings.Count() }).ToList()`

Comment: This is just a left join, did you even try to figure out how to do that in Linq? For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919230/asp-net-core-entityframework-core-left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: hmm, well one problem that might not be shown in my more simple example is that how to do the Where Clause? I want to filter down on properties in the EventTracking such as CreatedDate

Comment: @DavidG - Is it possible ot do a left join using the linq method way? Or I got to use the other way?

Comment: Other way? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Query syntax and Method syntax.

Comment: You know what might help? Google! Takes about 4 seconds...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods

Comment: @DavidG With navigation properties one don't need left, right or whatever explicit joins. And EF Core works/translates better implicit joins via navigation properties. People should stop thinking in SQL - see Camilo's comment containing simple answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev Indeed, but with the additional filter required on the navigation property, that would be awkward to do without a join.

Comment: Btw, once you add `where` with condition including the "right" side of the "left outer join" (other than `right IS NULL`), it effectively becomes "inner join".

Comment: @IvanStoev - Well the problem I am having is with Camilo is grouping it by Events.Name, Once I do a select, where and then try to the join. I don't have access to Events.Name

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I updated my code, the problem is I need to do some where clauses on fields int he EventTracking object so I am not sure how to do that then go back and group.

Comment: So the filter should be done on the count? How about `Count = evt.EventTrackings.Count(et => et.CreatedDate > new DateTime(2019, 4, 22))`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - Well that might work but I still need to also groupby CreatedDate

Comment: @chobo2 Are you saying that my last comment didn't work or what happened when you tried it? It should work as-is

Comment: It did not work as I can't access the CreatedDate from EventTracking to groupby.

Comment: How about something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9GT6mh)? It doesn't compile there but you can copy-paste it to run it

Comment: Here is your answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995454/linq-fluent-api-version-of-left-join-query